# GWT Tree styling

Tags: css, gwt, tree, uibinder

I have a normal Tree widget which I want to style. I know Tree widget has to following styles:

•.gwt-Tree { the tree itself }
•.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem { a tree item }
•.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem-selected { a selected tree item }

The webb people sent me this CSS and HTML as example how it should look like

css:

```
/* Menu styling */
    #menu li {
        margin-top: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        /*margin: 8px 0 8px 0;*/
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menuitems,.indented {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        border-width: 0;
        float: left;
        font-size: 100%;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .menuitems a { *
        display: block; *
        float: left; *
        clear: left;
    }

    .indented {
        border-left: 1px solid #005284;
        border-right: none;
        padding-left: 5px;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .menuitems a {
        color: #000000;
        display: block;
    }

    .menuitems a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .currentpage a {
        color: #C60;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

and html

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>
                <a href="abc">Option 1</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="abc">Option 2</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="abc">Option 3</a> 
                <ul class="indented">
                    <li class="currentpage">
                        <a href="blabla">subselection</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        subselection 2
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="abc">Option 4</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

I'm struggling a bit to get this to look as they want. I am using uibinder.

- Should I use a .css file or ui:style in the ui binder file?
- Do I need to remove the default styles with "removeStyleName" and setStyleName on every tree item?

Thx

Update:

Found out how to add images to leafs. Make an interface:

```
public interface TreeResources extends Resources {
     ImageResource treeOpen();
     ImageResource treeClosed();
  }
```

Create the tree with GWT.create.
make sure images with matching names (treeOpen.gif, treeClosed.gif) are in the same folder, or you could and annotations to point them out.

Question is how to get them on the right side instead of the left side?

Comment: Found out how to add images to leafs. Make and interface: public interface TreeResources extends Resources {

 ImageResource treeOpen(); 
 ImageResource treeClosed();
   
} make sure images with matching names are in the same folder. Question is how to get them on the right side instead?

Answer (score 1):

GWT does not expose a css class for the tree item, but you can easily do this for each `TreeItem` that you create:

```
TreeItem item = new TreeItem("click me!");
item.getElement().addClassName("gwt-TreeNode");                
tree.addItem(item);
```

Later you can add lines to the your tree like this:

```
.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeNode {
    border-left: 1px solid #005284;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While those are the correct CSS classes for selection, I found that the values I was trying to set were not updating correctly. The problem ended up being in the app's gwt.xml.

This line was in my app:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'
```

With this line, a default look/feel CSS was created called Clean.css. This was being loaded after my CSS file. Once I commented this line out, all of my settings were being applied.

Comment: My god ppl. its been 6 years... move on, I know I have :)

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Basically that the CSS tags were the right type, however I was including the Clean theme which was over-writting my selection. Once I took it out, the tags started working.

Comment: @AndreasBlomqvist some of us are only starting to use GWT now!